# How to start a countdown onclick with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

First, thank you for reading me. I am currently learning javascript, so... sorry for my code (and my bad english). Do not hesitate to make suggestion.

I am creating a (fake) website to book bikes in Toulouse (France). After users click on the #canvasbtn , i want to start a 20mn countdown / timer. At the end of the countdown, i would like to clear the sessionstorage & localstorage.

**Problem : the timer is starting when the page load (not when you click on #canvasbtn). And I can't find how to clear the localstorage when the countdown hit 0.**

https://github.com/ldoba/project-03

thank you for your help

```
const startingMinutes = 20;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;
const canvasbtn = document.querySelector('#canvasbtn');
const countdown = document.getElementById('timer');


//fonction minuteur 
function updateCountdown (){
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;
    let timerStatus = true;
    seconds= seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
    time--;

    if ((minutes + seconds) <= 0){
        clearInterval(interval);
        timerStatus = false;
    } else{
    }
}
//Interval pour rafraichissement chaque seconde
var interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

//le timer est activé après avoir appuyer sur le bouton du canvas
canvasbtn.onclick = updateCountdown();
```

Comment: fyi setInterval is not accurate

Comment: `canvasbtn.onclick = updateCountdown();` <--- wrong, should be `canvasbtn.onclick = updateCountdown;` or better yet `canvasbtn.addEventListener("click", updateCountdown);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments `canvasbtn.onclick = updateCountdown();` is wrong because you are executing the function and assigning it to the click.

Also setInterval is not accurate. And your countdown will not expire after 20 minutes after clicking the button. They would need to be sitting on the page for 20 minutes total (maybe you want that). You should be using date() to handle the diff in time.

Below I used Date() for the difference and store the values in localstorage. I only start the timer if the value is in storage or if the button is clicked.

```js
const maxTime = 20 * 1000 * 60 * 60;

const out = document.querySelector("#out");
function msToTime(duration) {
  let milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000));
  let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  // let hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  // hours = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  minutes = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  seconds = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  milliseconds = milliseconds.toString().padStart(3, '0');

  //return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
  return minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
}

let timer;
function countDown() {
  const diff = Date.now() - startTime;
  const remaining = Math.max(maxTime - diff, 0);
  if (remaining > 0) {
    out.textContent = msToTime(remaining);
    timer = window.setTimeout(countDown, 20);
  } else {
     out.textContent = 'complete';
     window.localStorage.removeItem('timer')
  }
}

const storageTime = window.localStorage.getItem('timer');
let startTime = storageTime ? +storageTime : null;

if (startTime) countDown();

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  startTime = Date.now();
  countDown();
  window.localStorage.setItem('timer', startTime);
});
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>

<button>start</button>
```

Comment: Wow ! Thank you a lot, really ! It's exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads the countdown starts because you directly calling your function that is assigned to interval variable.Just change the following and remove the varaible interval

```
var interval
canvasbtn.onclick = function(){
    interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000)
};
```

Add this before clearInterval to clear the localstorage

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Your suggestion will also immediately start the interval on page load.

Answer (score 0):

This line immediately starts your interval as soon as the page loads, and begins calling `updateCountdown` every second:

```
var interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
```

This line runs the function `updateCountdown` once as soon as the page loads:

```
canvasbtn.onclick = updateCountdown();
```

Then, because `updateCountdown` doesn't explicitly return anything, it assigns the value `undefined` to the `canvasbtn.onclick` event, which means that nothing will happen when you click your button.

What you'll want to do is remove this line entirely:

```
var interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
```

Then add `let interval = null` to the beginning of your code, and change your onclick to something like this:

```
canvasbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
})
```

By defining our `interval` variable outside the click handler, we allow it to be accessed later in our `updateCountdown` function, so you can clear it.

By wrapping the setInterval in a lambda (An anonymous function, this bit: `() => {...}`) we ensure that the interval is started when `canvasbtn` is clicked, and not on page load.

There are other issues with your code, and probably better ways of doing this than I've outlined here, but since you're learning I'm trying to keep my answer simple and focused. I don't want to do too much refactoring for you. I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your help and the simple answer. Have a great day